# adding python packages to uClinux

Tags: python, linux, package, uclinux

I have distribution of uClinux, throught "menu config" I check python
and compile("make").

I have python on my chip now.
There is a binary executable file /bin/python.

But what about python packages?
There are only some basic packages as sys, time etc.
I want to add for example package pyserial for serial port.

Before compilation I can in directory /python/modules in file "setup" select some packages.
But all of them are in C, how can I add generally python package to my distribution?

Thanks a lot for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at this page : http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/782203-python-board-os-uclinux ?

I'm not sure it will fulfill your needs, but it could :)